# I need some help with Croquet-Ground

Tags: adjectives, vocabulary

What's the meaning of "The Queen’s Croquet-Ground?" It's a chapter title , from Alice's Adventures in Wonderland.

Comment: As you will see as you continue reading, it is the ground belonging to the Queen upon which croquet is played.

Comment: Right! I will try not to be so hasty next time!

Comment: That is one of the best books in English literature. :)

Comment: It's a book full of intricacies. It's being easy to feel like I'm in the character's feet.

Comment: I think you mean: It's easy to feel like I'm in the character's shoes. :)

Comment: Oh, my. Sorry, I completely forgot!

Answer (score 1):

A "**croquet ground**" is an area used to play **croquet**.

Comment: So simple. But I don't know croquet...

Comment: It's not exactly the most popular of sports (if you can call it that), but it's a big part of the collective subconscious of Brits - *Alice* being one reason for that.

Comment: "it's a big part of the collective subconscious of Brits" - are you sure about that?

Comment: Well, perhaps only middle-class Brits. But I would say that most Brits are *aware* of croquet, even if they know nothing about it. I know some of the specialist words used in the game, but have no idea what any of them *mean*.

Comment: It's part of the whole image of what toffs do for recreation ;)